# Directions API with google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, google-maps, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I have a problem with the google-api-ruby-client as I can't find the proper way to discover the Directions API.

Here is the client:

```
@client = ::Google::APIClient.new :application_name => Rails.application.secrets.app_name
@client.key = Rails.application.secrets.google_public_api_key
```

and then

```
@client.discovered_api 'directions'     
@client.discovered_api 'directions', 'v1'
@client.discovered_api 'directions', 'v2'
@client.discovered_api 'directions', 'v3'
```

all fail with the same error:

```
Google::APIClient::ClientError: Not Found
```

I thought that the directions api could be within the maps API, so I tried with `'maps'` instead of `'directions'` and got the same errors.

I checked that my client works with

```
@client.discovered_api 'translate', 'v2'
```

which works properly.